# citation using bib file using author and year

Tags: biblatex

Can anyone help me to do citations in the text using author and year, importing them from/using a bib file.  I tried to use this code but doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{xxx.bib}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    citestyle=authoryear 
    ]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

 Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite {xxxx}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the log file when you compile your minimal document, you should have seen an error `Option Clash for package biblatex`.

This is because you are loading `biblatex` twice: once with no options (which defaults to a numeric style) and once with `alphabetic` style.

But if you want author-year style, you should load it with just the `[style=authoryear]` option.  If you actually want Author-Year citations but with an alpha style bibliography you can use `[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=alphabetic]`.

I've also changed the `\bibliography` command to `\addbibresource` (and moved it to a position after loading `biblatex`) and changed your `\cite` command to `\textcite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

 Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \textcite{mycitation}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```