# citations (author /year)

Tags: biblatex

I used this code to do citations for the following reference

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{SMC_paper.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{al2004sliding}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

this reference:

```
@article{al2004sliding, 
  title = {Sliding mode control of a magnetic levitation system}, 
  author = {Al-Muthairi, NF and Zribi, M}, 
  journal = {Mathematical Problems in Engineering}, 
  volume = {2004},
  number = {2},
  pages = {93--107},
  year = {2004},
  publisher = {Hindawi Publishing Corporation} 
}
```

but it gives me this result

> Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper **al2004sliding**

Comment: Mhhh, isn't this more or less a copy of the "answer" you wrote to your own question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268728/35864?

Comment: Please also report warnings and errors from your `.log` and `.blg` files. If you can't find a `.blg` file, it is very likely you didn't run Biber, see [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If your `.blg` file mentions BibTeX and not Biber you need to make sure to run Biber and not BibTeX.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: I have voted as a duplicate of the "standard" [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), the problem seems to be the same and the OP did not respond to further inquiries.